# Terminate Local Apache Server on port 80

Tags: apache, localhost, port

I am currently running Ubuntu and doing some symphony2 tutorials but when I tried to open a new server on port 80 with the command : 

 *php -S localhost:80 -t*

in the Symfony folder it was already said to be in use. When I used the command 
 
*sudo fuser -v 80/tcp*

to find the use I get the following: 
 
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND 
80/tcp:              root       1091 F.... apache2
                     www-data   1095 F.... apache2 
                     www-data   1096 F.... apache2

I have no idea what is running but I do get the following message when I go to my local host in Mozilla:

"It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

So my question is how do I close down this server and how would I find out what is running? If this question has already been asked I apologize. Thank you in advance.